# Any standard functionality to popup error message on validate fields

Tags: validation

I want to validate three fields and any one of them is not satisfied, after click on the button, should fire one dialogue box with error message. Is there any standard functionality to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard functionality you can`t create popups. If it is important for you to have a popup you will have to use javascript on that button or create a visualforce page.

However if you just need to display an error near a field or on the top of your page standard validation might work for you like that:

```
OR( ISBLANK(field1), ISBLANK(field2), ISBLANK(field3) )
```